# How to dynamic render child Array component in react

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, react-hooks

I want to render dynamic component But I cannot able to render children component nextcomp[]. currently only first component Text rendering.

```
const item = [{
    component: "text",
    label: "Name",
    Type: "text",
    nextComp: [{
        component: "checkbox",
        label: "yes",
        question: "Do you Play football",
        type: "checkbox",
    }, {
        component: "text",
        label: "Age",
        Type: "text",
        nextComp: [{
            component: "checkbox",
            label: "yes",
            question: "Do you Play football",
            type: "checkbox",
        }, {
            component: "text",
            label: "Gender",
            Type: "text",
        }],
    }],
}, ]
```

**App.js I mapped like**

```
{item.map(block => Components(block))}
```

**I am rendering component like**

```
const Components = {
      Text: Text,
      checkbox: Checkbox
    };
    
export default block => {
  if (typeof Components[block.component] !== "undefined") {
    return React.createElement(Components[block.component], {
      key: block,
      block: block
    });
  }
  return React.createElement(
    () => <View>The component {block.component} has not been created yet.</View>,
    { key: block}
  );

};
```

Comment: Can you fix the code formatting of `item` so it's easier to read? Also, I don't believe it's generally correct to call `React.createElement yourself. Can you provide a bit more context around this code and how it's used/called so it clearer why it it what it is?

Comment: Drew Reese Please check json again I want to render nextcomp How can i perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I sort of understand what you are going for here. I don't see where your recursive renderer function recurses on the `block.nextComp` array.

[React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

> ```
> React.createElement(
>   type,
>   [props],
>   [...children]
> )
> ```

Map the `block.nextComp` to this renderer and pass the result as the third argument.

```
const Components = {
  Text: Text,
  checkbox: Checkbox
};

const renderBlock = block => {
  if (typeof Components[block.component] !== "undefined") {
    return React.createElement(
      Components[block.component],
      {
        key: block,
        block: block
      },
      block.nextComp?.map(renderBlock) || null,
    );
  }
  return React.createElement(
    () => <View>The component {block.component} has not been created yet.</View>,
    { key: block}
  );
};

export default renderBlock;
```

### Update

I think you've a typo in your `Components` object, `"Text"` isn't a key referenced in your `item` array objects. Update the key to match usage.

```
const Components = {
  text: Text,
  checkbox: Checkbox
};
```

To make rendering the `item` array a little more clear, you might want to give the imported recursive renderer a more meaningful/clear name. Map the `item` array the same way the `block.nextComp` was mapped.

```
import renderBlock from '../path/to/renderBlock';

...

{item.map(renderBlock)}
```

See this running codesandbox demo:

[image: Edit how-to-dynamic-render-child-array-component-in-react]

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer but I added exact same above code but it still render only first text component not child nextcomp[]. please help me in this

Comment: Can you please tell me where I am going wrong I am new in react

Comment: @ReactDev I'll try to create a running codesandbox demo.

Comment: @ReactDev Ok, seems to work, just needed a little tweak to the `Components` definition, and assumes the `Text` and `Checkbox` components correctly render the `children` prop.

Comment: Thank you for Answer But if I want to render label of all text and all checkbox label with single line. Actually I want to make text and checkbox a dynamic components How can i do this

Comment: Like this example https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-components-from-json-with-react-ybq27?fontsize=14&file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ReactDev All the values are passed in on the `block` prop, you can access the label values there. Example: `props.block.label`. See updated codesandbox.

Comment: It solved my problem I need to know why you use {props.children} is this build in prop?

Comment: @ReactDev Yes.... all React components have a `children` prop. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241570/discussion-between-react-dev-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @ReactDev Responded in chat.